# Are transfer credits transitive?

Tags: transfer-student, accreditation

Is transfer credit transitive?  If B accepts credits from A, and C accepts credits from B, will C accept credits from A, provided a student transfers to B before coming to C?

I have transfer credits at my current, American, university.  Some of them are from a previous American university, some of them are from a foreign high school, and some are from online classes.  If I transfer, will the university I transfer *to* accept my current transfer credit just as it does any credit from my current university?

Something I'm looking at now is online classes from [Saylor](https://www.saylor.org/).  I'm just afraid that even if my current university accepts ACE credit, if I transfer, these credits may not follow me.

Comment: What is ACE credit?

Comment: The American Council on Education (ACE) has a program in which they evaluate non college training and make recommendations to colleges about what credit should be given for this training.  For example, a person who served in the US Army might have attended military training courses in electronics, and ACE might recommend that these should be considered to be equivalent to 12 credit hours of coursework in electronics engineering technology.  Institutions aren’t required to accept ACE credit, and the OP has good reason to worry that his ACE credit might be accepted at another institution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, in the US, universities generally transfer credit from where it was originally earned.  The fact that school B transferred credit from school A is does not ensure that school C will accept the credit.  Furthermore, school C will generally require a transcript from school A.

Answer (score 5):

The only valid answer you will get is from the institution you are applying to. They likely have policies about all sort of such things. As a pure guess it would depend on the individual institutions that granted the credits originally and their reputation.

A "receiving" institution might be fairly open to this if they have reason to want you for other considerations. But ask and you will learn.

In the US, at least, don't look for common policies. Within a State university system there may be rules about transferring from one such institution to another.

Comment: In fact, they hire so many people to endlessly make policy it will blow your mind